# XAML Create ControlTemplate for Map PushPin

Tags: wpf, xaml, bing-maps, pushpin

I am trying to customize the template for a map pushpin. Not windows 8 mobile, this is just a WPF map control. I can't get XAML to recognize the TargetType. I have to specify the TargetType so I can modify certain elements not found in a generic Control. I've tried several variations. The code exists in a XAML file separate from the WPF UserControl (gets referenced in the MergedDictionaries). Code below:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Maps.MapControl.WPF">

    <ControlTemplate x:Key="PushPinTemplate" TargetType="m:PushPin" >
        <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                MinHeight="31"
                                                MinWidth="29">
                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                               Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                               ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                               Margin="4"/>
                </Grid>
                <Polygon Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                                             Points="0,0 29,0 0,29"
                                                             Width="29"
                                                             Height="29"
                                                             HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Setting PushPin.Template in C#

```
pushpin.Template = (ControlTemplate)(Resources["PushPinTemplate"]);
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done it in WPF but I know when I do this in like store apps or SL etc I use a Style Template for the pushpin instead of ControlTemplate and then it can be called like `pushpin.Style = this.Resources["PushPinTemplate"] as Style;` instead, not sure if that's helpful or not so just added as comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type name is not written correctly. It is [`Pushpin`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.wpf.pushpin.aspx), not `PushPin`:

```
<ControlTemplate ... TargetType="m:Pushpin">
```

Comment: I verified this is actually the issue. I was going back and forth between casings, which is why the issue was so inconsistent. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have missed the `{x:Type }` declaration

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="PushPinTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type m:PushPin}" >
```

This means that you are supplying a string to the TargetType instead of a Type

> The x:Type markup extension supplies a from-string conversion behavior for properties that take the type Type. The input is a XAML type.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thought I had tried this before. This worked. Thanks!

Comment: `TargetType="m:PushPin"` is valid XAML. Don't know since which WPF version, but it's implicitly handled as Type, not as string, just as if you had written `{x:Type ...}`. The problem here is that the correct type name is `Pushpin`, not `PushPin`.